# R: Packrat init() returns error "cannot set reparse point" and "target already exists and is not a symlink"

Tags: r, packrat

I wanted to try [packrat](http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/), but I ran into a warning and error message upon initializing it on a project:

```
> library(packrat)
> packrat::init()
Initializing packrat project in directory:
- "\\userhome/myuser/R_scripts/ratpack_test"

Adding these packages to packrat:
            _        
    packrat   0.4.8-1

Fetching sources for packrat (0.4.8-1) ... OK (CRAN current)
Snapshot written to "\\userhome/myuser/R_scripts/ratpack_test/packrat/packrat.lock"
Installing packrat (0.4.8-1) ... 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/packrat_0.4.8-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 192726 bytes (188 KB)
downloaded 188 KB

    OK (downloaded binary)
Initialization complete!
Warning message:
In Sys.junction(from, to) :
  cannot set reparse point '\\userhome/myuser/R_scripts/ratpack_test/packrat/lib-R/base', reason 'Incorrect function'

Restarting R session...

Error in ensurePackageSymlink(source, target) : 
  Target '\\userhome/myuser/R_scripts/ratpack_test/packrat/lib-R/base' already exists and is not a symlink
```

It says `cannot set reparse point 'my_custom_path', reason 'Incorrect function'`, and `Target already exists and is not a symlink`. Has anybody experienced a similar behavior? I'm running R 3.2.0 and Windows10.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] packrat_0.4.8-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Comment: For starters, I'd upgrade your version of R. The current version is 3.4.1 and strange things can happen when you're two decimals behind.

Comment: I cannot upgrade R because my enterprise uses this version of R

Comment: Understood, that's frustrating